# Unable to access iframe content (same-origin policy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have the following page

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loopLink(i) 
    {
        window.open($('#iframe_a').contents().find('.image-navigator-mid a').attr('href'),'iframe_a');
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (i < 3) loopLink(i+1);
        }, 5000);
    }
    // Wait for the page to load first
    window.onload = function() {

      var a = document.getElementById("mylink");

      a.onclick = function() {
        loopLink(0);
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
<iframe src="http://nanofate.us/content/fate-new-hair-style#node-inner" width="500" height="500" name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
<br />
<a id="mylink" href="">Execute</a>
```

the idea is that in it's current form, when you click Execute, the javascript will cause the iframe to use the "previous" link 4 times, waiting 5 second each time, however when i click the link it just reloads the page and even after waiting 10 seconds the iframe is doing nothing

i am wondering what i have done wrong

Comment: And the iframe is showing a page from the same domain as the site ?

Comment: @adeneo no, what i'm trying to make is a page which when you run the script, will loop though the entire gallery and download every image, but first i need to be able to loop[ though the entire gallery

Comment: Have a look at same origin policy http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: If it's not from the same domain, you don't have access to the iframe for security reasons, see the above link, and no, there's no way around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy) restrictions, you can not access contents of iframe if it is running a page from another domain. There are solutions to same domain policy like

- Opening a page via a proxy

Check out [Tomodo](http://tomodo.com/faq/). It is just to give you a hint how they used proxy to bypass same origin policy constraint and access iframe content. So the implementation idea goes like this

- Create a proxy and host it at `a.com/proxy`
- Host your main page at `a.com/index.html`
- Now, request your proxy to give you content of iframe_url something like this `a.com/proxy?url=iframe_url.com`

*Please note this is not a trivial task* and you may have to handle a lot of cases at your proxy like **handling relative URLs**, **cookie reading by iframe_url** etc etc.
So go for it only if you need it desperately.

### Another solution might be this:

If you want to download some images for a particular domain, just ask your server side code to it for you. Your backend code will fetch the html of page and use some HTML parser like

- **BeautifulSoup for python** ([Documentation Link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4))
- **Jsoup for Java** ([Documentation Link](http://jsoup.org/))

to parse img tags and extract the source and fetch the images and download them.

**PS**: Just for some good information, please read [Ways to circumvent same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/1310070)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is subject to the same origin policy. This should be the reason why you are getting permission denied type errors.